# How to delete the last line of the file in scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to append to a file such that I first want to delete the last line and then start appending. But, I can't figure how to delete the last line of the file.

I am appending the file as follows:

```
val fw = new FileWriter("src/file.txt", true) ;
fw.write("new item");
```

Can anybody please help me?

EDIT:

```
val lines_list = Source.fromFile("src/file.txt").getLines().toList 
val new_lines = lines_list.dropRight(1) 
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("src/file.txt" )) 
(t).foreach(pw.write) pw.write("\n") 
pw.close()
```

After following your method, I am trying to write back to the file, but when I do this, all the contents, with the last line deleted come in a single line, however I want them to come in separate lines.

Comment: You can not just delete last line in the file. You have to create new file without the last line. Or use FileChannel: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: I would load the text lines into a list and drop the last item, then start appending.

Comment: If your file is small - it is OK. But what if it is 1GB or more?

Comment: Well yeah, depends on the scenario.

Comment: @Marcs : Could you please look at the edit in the question and tell me how to proceed?

Comment: I used pw.println instead of pw.write and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Ok good, yeah i wanted to point that.

Answer (score 1):

For very large files a simple solution relies in OS related tools, for instance `sed` (stream editor), and so consider a call like this,

```
import sys.process._
Seq("sed","-i","$ d","src/file1.txt")!
```

which will remove the last line of the text file. This approach is not so Scalish yet it solves the problem without leaving Scala.

Comment: It says unterminated substitute pattern. :O

Answer (score 0):

My scala is way off, so people can probably give you a nicer solution:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._

object Test00 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val lines = Source.fromFile("src/file.txt").getLines().toList.dropRight(1)

    val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("src/out.txt" ))

    (lines :+ "another line").foreach(pw.println)

    pw.close()
  }
}
```

Sorry for the hardcoded appending, i used it just to test that everything worked fine.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your way and  I do like this: 

val lines_list = Source.fromFile("src/file.txt").getLines().toList
 val new_lines = lines_list.dropRight(1)
 
 
 
 val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("src/file.txt" ))
    (t).foreach(pw.write)
    pw.write("\n")
    pw.close()

But, it gives me the elements that were there in the file after deleting the last line in a single line; how can I add "\n" between each line and then write it to the file?

Comment: This one is using a pw. Not the best if the text file is big.

Answer (score 0):

Return random access file in position without last line.

```scala
import java.io.{RandomAccessFile, File}

  def randomAccess(file: File) = {
    val random = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")

    val result = findLastLine(random, 0, 0)
    random.seek(result)
    random
  }

  def findLastLine(random: RandomAccessFile, position: Long, previous: Long): Long = {

    val pointer = random.getFilePointer
    if (random.readLine == null) {
      previous
    } else {
      findLastLine(random, previous, pointer)
    }
  }


  val file = new File("build.sbt")
  val random = randomAccess(file)
```

And test:

```
  val line = random.readLine()
  logger.debug(s"$line")
```